# Crashing while Adding NSMutableDictionary to NSMutableArray in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, firebase, nsmutabledictionary

I was trying to save some data into fire base.So the format is like am adding contents into NSMutableDictionary and then am adding that into NSMutableArray and sending to FireBase.For first time it was working when i tried to add second contents its crashing with following message

```
2014-12-08 14:36:43.388 ChangeText[1634:576618] -[__NSArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17023e580
2014-12-08 14:36:43.392 ChangeText[1634:576618] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17023e580'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x184db259c 0x1954c00e4 0x184db9664 0x184db6418 0x184cbab6c 0x1000fce74 0x189598d34 0x189581e48 0x1895986d0 0x18959835c 0x1895918b0 0x189564fa8 0x189803f58 0x189563510 0x184d6a9ec 0x184d69c90 0x184d67d40 0x184c950a4 0x18de3f5a4 0x1895ca3c0 0x1000fd7ec 0x195b2ea08)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

My code

Viewdidload

```
  arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    Firebase *fire=[[Firebase alloc]initWithUrl:@"http://del.firebaseio.com/users"];
    [fire observeEventType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
       // self.status.text=snapshot.value;
        NSLog(@"snapshot%@",snapshot.value);
        arr=[snapshot.value copy];

        NSLog(@"copied%@",arr);


    }];
```

Button to add values into Firebase

```
// arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [dict setValue:@"test1" forKey:@"username"];
    [dict setValue:@"test2" forKey:@"password"];
    [dict setValue:@"test3" forKey:@"profilepic"];
    [dict setValue:@"test4" forKey:@"profile"];
    [dict setValue:@"test5" forKey:@"details"];
    [arr addObject:dict];
    NSLog(@"added new elements%@",arr);

    Firebase *f=[[Firebase alloc]initWithUrl:@"http://del.firebaseio.com/users"];
    [f setValue:arr ];
```

My console logs

```
2014-12-08 14:36:32.017 ChangeText[1634:576618] snapshot(
        {
        details = test5;
        password = test2;
        profile = test4;
        profilepic = test3;
        username = test1;
    }
)
2014-12-08 14:36:32.019 ChangeText[1634:576618] copied(
        {
        details = test5;
        password = test2;
        profile = test4;
        profilepic = test3;
        username = test1;
    }
)
2014-12-08 14:36:43.388 ChangeText[1634:576618] -[__NSArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17023e580
2014-12-08 14:36:43.392 ChangeText[1634:576618] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17023e580'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x184db259c 0x1954c00e4 0x184db9664 0x184db6418 0x184cbab6c 0x1000fce74 0x189598d34 0x189581e48 0x1895986d0 0x18959835c 0x1895918b0 0x189564fa8 0x189803f58 0x189563510 0x184d6a9ec 0x184d69c90 0x184d67d40 0x184c950a4 0x18de3f5a4 0x1895ca3c0 0x1000fd7ec 0x195b2ea08)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Please help me to fix this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arr = [snapshot.value copy];
```

The above line assigns `NSArray` type instance to your `arr` object. That's the reason when you try to add objects in your array, it gets crashed because the current instance is of type `NSArray`, not `NSMutableArray`. Replace above line with the following line:

```
[arr addObjectsFromArray:snapshot.value];
```

Comment: How do we check whether snapshot.value is null or not??

Comment: perform a `nil` check: `if (snapchot.value) { [arr addObjectsFromArray:snapchot.value] }`

Comment: This is a wrong answer, `copy` normally returns immutable copy, for mutable there is `mutableCopy`

Comment: The OP is trying to add objects from array. Not copying the response array. It's not about copying. I know the difference between `copy` and `mutableCopy`..

Comment: You don't have to copy then at all. You suggest him to use copy in  `addObjectsFromArray:`. When you fill up mutable array with other array you don't have to copy anything. Copy is redundant in here.

Comment: Edited according to your suggestion.. btw I just saw that I used copy for objects while adding.. I also didn't mean to use copy.. :p

Answer (score 2):

`[arr addObject:dict];` is creating the crash in this case, since `arr` is Immutable.

`arr=[snapshot.value copy];` gives you an immutable copy of object. You could try with

`arr=[snapshot.value mutableCopy];`

Comment: @NaveenKumar: basically its same.

Comment: yup,i tried yours also both are same , but one doubt how do we get rid of when first time snapshot.value equal to null?2014-12-08 15:22:01.536 Delibro[1699:589610] snapshot<null>
2014-12-08 15:22:01.538 Delibro[1699:589610] *** -[NSMutableArray addObjectsFromArray:]: array argument is not an NSArray
2014-12-08 15:22:01.544 Delibro[1699:589610] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray addObjectsFromArray:]: array argument is not an NSArray'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x184db259c

Comment: You can do a nil/null check, as  `if (dict){ [arr addObject:dict] }`